# Get data from a method on the server side using jquery and NodeJS

Tags: jquery, node.js, express

I have a NodeJS Express server, and it contains this method

```
function GetYears(User) {
  let Years = []
  let user = GetUserData(User);
  user.History.forEach(i => {
    Years.push(i.Year);
  });
  return Years;
}
```

How can I use jquery to run the method and return the 'Years' array to be used like this on a HTML page.

```
<script>
    $(()=>{
        let x = ['Name','Surname','Age']
        x.forEach(i=>{
            $('#Headers').append(`<th>${i}</th>`);
        })
    });
</script>
```

where 'x' will be the Array returned from the server.

Comment: I am not getting what you'd like to achieve. So NodeJS will return `Years` (I suppose with an API call?) and on the browser what should happen?

Comment: I am using express to run a web server and on the browser it will fill a table row <tr>#</tr> with the array data when the page loads, the data should be called from the NodeJS server.

Comment: So, I suppose there's an API endpoint jQuery will call? Or you're expecting Express to serve the HTML page with JS printed inside, ready to be executed by the browser with the data of the `Years` array already printed in the HTML page sent to the brwoser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I figured it out for anyone else trying to do the same there seems to be a lot of different ways of doing it but this is my attempt, in my HTML page I used this:

```
$(()=>{
        $.post( "/GetYears",{User:'Jake'}, function( data ) {
                data.data.forEach(i => {
                $("#Year").append(`<option value="${i}">${i}</option>`);
            });
        });
    });
```

And on my server I did this:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.post('/GetYears',(req,res)=>{
  let User = req.body.User;
  res.json({data:Handle.GetYears(User)});
})

app.listen(8000);
```

I changed the table to a dropdown select, got the years data from the server then populated the dropdown with it.

Answer (score 1):

Via an API? :-)

On backend (Node.js & Express), you'd have a [Route](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/basic-routing.html) which send's the return value of `GetYears`.

On frontend (Jquery), you'd [$.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) that route's url and process the result.